# i would like to loop through a dataframe ( pd python) and do something with previous 5 row at a time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i would like to loop through a dataframe ( pd python) and do something with previous 5 row at a time

```
for row in dataframe:
    features = dataframe['low'].iloc[-(lags + 1):row.index-1]
    print(features)
    features = features.values.reshape(1, -1)
    print(features)
    row['signal'] = algorithm.predict(features)[0]
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: that would work if i would need a attribute like mean or variance